# Implementation of Luhn credit card algorithm

Tags: python, performance, checksum

I've implemented [Luhn's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) for checking credit card numbers.
My code works, but I wanted to learn about a more efficient and more Pythonic way of doing this.

```
def validate_credit_card_number(card_number):
    #start writing your code here

    #Step 1a - complete
    temp_list=list(str(card_number))
    my_list=[]
    list1 = temp_list[-2::-2]
    list2=temp_list[::-2]
    list2 = [int (n) for n in list2]
    #print(list2)
    my_list=[int(n) for n in list1]
    #print(my_list)
    list1 = [int(n)*2 for n in list1]
    t_list=list1

    for el in list1:
        sum_res=0

        if el>9:
            idx = list1.index(el)
            t_list.pop(idx)

            while el:
                rem = el%10
                sum_res+=rem
                el = el//10 
            t_list.insert(idx, sum_res)
    #print(t_list)

    #step 1b

    list1_sum=sum(t_list)
    list2_sum = sum(list2)
    #print(b_list)
    final_sum = list1_sum+ list2_sum
    #print(final_sum)

    if final_sum%10==0:
        return True
    return False

card_number= 1456734512345698 #4539869650133101  #1456734512345698 # #5239512608615007

result=validate_credit_card_number(card_number)
if(result):
    print("credit card number is valid")
else:
    print("credit card number is invalid")
```

Comment: (Welcome to Code Review!) (This question seems to be getting smoother by the edit…)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Josay's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/209689/187192) is right on the money in terms of how to start optimizing one's Python code.

Below I go further with the optimization that Josay started. I should warn that the code is at a stage where optimizations begin to really flirt with readability, and so for shared code that must be understood and maintained, we're home safe.

If we desire to get a "one-liner" Python script, for what it's worth, let's look at the difference between `list1` and `list2`. As a side-note about style, more descriptive names of these lists might be `evens` and `odds`: hints that would really help the person who has to read your code.

### Finding commonality in how the odds even digits are handled

Recall that for our sum, we will be adding up all the numbers in `odds`. We will, in fact, also be adding up all the digits in `evens`, except we will *also* add them up again (doubling). Then we also need to account for the cases when the doubling results in two-digit numbers, but more on that below.

Since both `odds` and `evens` adds each digit, we could start off with just adding up all the digits:

```python
def validate_credit_card_number(card_number):     #incomplete code
    temp_list = [int(c) for c in str(card_number)]
    return ( sum(temp_list) + CORRECTIONS ) % 10 == 0
```

So what are the corrections we need to make? Well, every other digit needs to be added again. Instead of dividing the list up into `evens` and `odds` and separating the problems, what if we had some sort of *indicator* that we are processing an odd or an even digit?

### Correcting for the even numbers

One possible answer is to somehow look up the *index* of the digit we are processing, and seeing if that one is odd or even. The check for whether `i` is odd is just `(i % 2) == 1`.

But what's a good way of getting to know both the index of the digit and the digit itself? Python has a nice built-in iterator called [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). Formally, `enumerate` gives you a generator that provides (index,element) pairs from a list. To illustrate, `enumerate (["foo","bar",7,"zoo"])` returns a generator for `[(0, 'foo'), (1, 'bar'), (2, 7), (3, 'zoo')]`. Great! Let's see if we can use that.

```python
def validate_credit_card_number(card_number):     #incomplete code
    temp_list = [int(c) for c in str(card_number)]
    return sum([ x + (x if (i % 2)==0 else 0) for (i,x) in enumerate(temp_list)]) % 10 == 0
```

Here we use Python's `a if <test> else b` ternary notation to check if the number is the even number.

### Thinking backwards

But wait ... the Luhn specification said we needed to start counting from the *right-most* digit. So what if that digit happens to have an even index? Our odds and evens would be exactly switched! Here, we would notice that it'd be so much more convenient to just count from the right. All we are doing is adding up numbers, so it wouldn't make any difference if we were to just reverse the list first! We just have to be careful that the rightmost digit in the reverse list (`temp_list`) is now at index 0, so we must now be correcting the *odd* numbers.

```python
def validate_credit_card_number(card_number):     #incomplete code
    temp_list = reversed([int(c) for c in str(card_number)])
    return sum([ x + (x if (i % 2)==1 else 0) for (i,x) in enumerate(temp_list)]) % 10 == 0
```

### Fixing the double digit cases

Much better. But, alas, there is still an issue with the double digits. If the digit at the even index is 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4, we actually do the right thing: double the number. But if it's 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9, we are currently adding 10, 12, 14, 16, 18 instead of 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, respectively. But for those numbers, the difference between what we do now and what we should do is always 9! How about adding a check for whether the digit is 5 or more, in which case subtract 9?

```python
def validate_credit_card_number(card_number):
    temp_list = reversed([int(c) for c in str(card_number)])
    return sum([ x + (x + (-9 if x>=5 else 0) if (i % 2)==1 else 0) for (i,x) in enumerate(temp_list)]) % 10 == 0
```

This code actually works!

### Simplifying with modulus tricks

Let's keep going! If we add -9 to a sum that we are reducing modulo 10, that's the same as adding 1 to the sum. Why? Because \$-9 \pmod{10} \equiv 10 + (-9) \pmod{10} \equiv 1 \pmod{10}\$ since the extra 10 doesn't change the modulus. It's a bit like saying that 9 hours ago, the clock hand pointed at the same number as it will do \$(12-9)=3\$ hours from now -- except that clocks work modulo 12.

```python
def validate_credit_card_number(card_number):
    temp_list = reversed([int(c) for c in str(card_number)])
    return sum([ x + (x + (1 if x>=5 else 0) if (i % 2)==1 else 0) for (i,x) in enumerate(temp_list)]) % 10 == 0
```

### Multiplication instead of ternary operator

Also, we can replace the ternary operators (the `if` business) with simple multiplication. Why? Because there is no difference between `8 + (42 if x%2==1 else 0)` and `8 + 42*(x%2)`. Further, something like `8 + (1 if x%2==1 else 0)` could just be simplified to `8 + (x%2)`.

Using these ideas, we now have:

```python
def validate_credit_card_number(card_number): 
    temp_list = reversed([int(c) for c in str(card_number)])
    return sum([ x + (x+(x>=5))*(i%2) for (i,x) in enumerate(temp_list)]) % 10 == 0
```

### Mapping to a one-liner

Nice. Now, can we squeeze this whole expression into a single line, just because? Here, we may notice that the list comprehension for `temp_list` is really just applying `int` to every character in `card_number`. There is another nice built-in function in Python called [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), a descendant from [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) languages, that takes a function and a list, and applies the function to each element of a list. (From a Pythonic style perspective, bear in mind that [generator expressions are usually favorable to map, which almost got removed in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015439/why-does-map-return-a-map-object-instead-of-a-list-in-python-3)).

```python
def validate_credit_card_number(card_number): 
    temp_list = reversed(list (map(int, [c for c in str(card_number)])))
    return sum([ x + (x+(x>=5))*(i%2) for (i,x) in enumerate(temp_list)]) % 10 == 0
```

### One-liner ahoy!

Wait a minute. When we see `[c for c in str(card_number)]`, we should pause and think about what list we are really generating. When you think about it, `str(card_number)` return a string, and Python strings implement an [iterator](http://zetcode.com/lang/python/itergener/). So for our purposes, we could just treat `str(card_number)` as a list of characters! This gives:

```python
def validate_credit_card_number(card_number): 
    temp_list = reversed(list (map(int, str(card_number))))
    return sum([ x + (x+(x>=5))*(i%2) for (i,x) in enumerate(temp_list)]) % 10 == 0
```

The `list` bit is ugly. So let's reverse the string earlier and conclude with:

```python
def validate_credit_card_number(card_number): 
    return sum([x + (x+(x>=5))*(i%2) for (i,x) in enumerate(map(int, reversed(str(card_number))))]) % 10 == 0
```

### Shorter still?

There are still opportunities to shorten the expression. For one, we could assume that the input is actually a string already. For another, we can remove the reversal business and just figure out if the doubling should happen for evens or odds by looking at the length of the input string. This gives:

```python
def validate_credit_card_number(card_str): 
    return sum([x + (x+(x>=5))*((len(card_str)-1+i)%2) for (i,x) in enumerate(map(int, card_str))]) % 10 == 0
```

Comment: I'm really taken back. Just one line. 

Comment: Welcome here! This is a very nice answer, I'm looking forward to reading more of your contributions in the near future!

Answer (score 13):

**Style**

Python has a style guide called [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It is a good habit to try to follow it.

In your case, that would mean fixing the missing whitespaces, removing parenthesis in `if(result)`.

Also, you could get rid of old commented code and add a proper [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) if you want to describe the behavior of the function.

**Tests**

It could be a good idea to write tests before trying to improve your code.

I wrote a very simple code but you could get this chance to dive into unit testing frameworks:

```
TESTS = [
    (1456734512345698, False),
    (4539869650133101, True),
    (1456734512345698, False),
    (5239512608615007, True),
]

for (card_number, expected_valid) in TESTS:
    valid = validate_credit_card_number(card_number)
    assert valid == expected_valid
```

**Useless test**

At the end of the function, you can return directly:

```
return final_sum % 10 == 0
```

**Useless variables**

The `my_list` variable is not required.

Also, we can take this chance to get rid of the variables at the end of the function:

```
return (sum(t_list) + sum(list2)) % 10 == 0
```

**Conversion of `card_number`**

At the beginning of the function, you could convert the parts of `card_number` directly to integer so that you do it in a single place.
Also, that removed the need to the call of `list`. We just have:

```
temp_list = [int(c) for c in str(card_number)]
```

And we can get rid of the line:

```
list2 = [int (n) for n in list2]
```

At this stage, the code looks like:

```
def validate_credit_card_number(card_number):
    temp_list = [int(c) for c in str(card_number)]

    list1 = temp_list[-2::-2]
    list1 = [2 * n for n in list1]

    list2 = temp_list[::-2]

    t_list = list1

    for el in list1:
        sum_res = 0

        if el > 9:
            idx = list1.index(el)
            t_list.pop(idx)

            while el:
                rem = el % 10
                sum_res += rem
                el = el // 10
            t_list.insert(idx, sum_res)

    return (sum(t_list) + sum(list2)) % 10 == 0
```

**Yet another useless variable**

`t_list` aliases `list1` (I am not sure if this is intended if if you were planning to have a copy of `list1`). Whenever you update the list through one variable, the other is affected as well. I highly recommend [Ned Batchelder's talk about names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html).

In your case, we can get rid of `t_list` completely without changing the behavior of the function.

**Simplify list logic**

You go through multiple steps to modify `list1` (or `t_list`) : `index`, `pop`, `index`. These steps are more expensive/complicated than required. At the end of the day, you do not care about `list1`, you just want its final sum. You could keep track of the sum directly:

```
sum1 = 0
for el in list1:
    if el > 9:
        sum_res = 0
        while el:
            rem = el % 10
            sum_res += rem
            el = el // 10
        sum1 += sum_res
    else:
        sum1 += el

return (sum1 + sum(list2)) % 10 == 0
```

We can take this chance to perform the multiplication in the loop to remove a list comprehension.

Also, we can initialise the sum with `sum(list2)` so that we don't have to add them at the end:

```
def validate_credit_card_number(card_number):
    temp_list = [int(c) for c in str(card_number)]

    list1 = temp_list[-2::-2]
    list2 = temp_list[::-2]

    total_sum = sum(list2)
    for el in list1:
        el *= 2
        if el > 9:
            sum_res = 0
            while el:
                rem = el % 10
                sum_res += rem
                el = el // 10
            total_sum += sum_res
        else:
            total_sum += el

    return total_sum % 10 == 0
```

**Math logic**

The code uses 10 (the base used for computations) everywhere except for one 9 which seems unexpected. You could write: `el >= 10` instead.

Also, that check is not required because the logic applies exactly the same way for elements smaller than 10:

```
for el in list1:
    el *= 2
    sum_res = 0
    while el:
        rem = el % 10
        sum_res += rem
        el = el // 10
    total_sum += sum_res
```

Also, you could use `el //= 10` but you can get the best ouf of the Python builtins by using [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) returning both the quotient and the remainder:

```
    while el:
        el, rem = divmod(el, 10)
        sum_res += rem
    total_sum += sum_res
```

Then, it becomes clear that the variable `sum_res` is not really required as we could use `total_sum` instead:

```
    while el:
        el, rem = divmod(el, 10)
        total_sum += rem
```

**"Final" code**

```
def validate_credit_card_number(card_number):
    temp_list = [int(c) for c in str(card_number)]

    list1 = temp_list[-2::-2]
    list2 = temp_list[::-2]

    total_sum = sum(list2)
    for el in list1:
        el *= 2
        while el:
            el, rem = divmod(el, 10)
            total_sum += rem

    return total_sum % 10 == 0

TESTS = [
    (1456734512345698, False),
    (4539869650133101, True),
    (1456734512345698, False),
    (5239512608615007, True),
]

for (card_number, expected_valid) in TESTS:
    valid = validate_credit_card_number(card_number)
    assert valid == expected_valid
```

**More simplification**

Thinking about it, things can still be simplified a lot.
What you are doing with the `while` loop can be performed using `str` conversion:

```
total_sum = sum(list2)
for el in list1:
    total_sum += sum(int(c) for c in str(2 * el))
```

Going further (too far?), this leads to:

```
def validate_credit_card_number(card_number):
    temp_list = [int(c) for c in str(card_number)]

    list1 = temp_list[-2::-2]
    list2 = temp_list[::-2]

    total_sum = sum(list2) + sum(sum(int(c) for c in str(2 * el)) for el in list1)
    return total_sum % 10 == 0
```

Edit:

**More simplification**

We are using `str` and `int` to get the digits of a number... which is known to be smaller than 18 (2 * 9).
A trick could be, once again, to use `divmod` returning the quotient and remainder and use sum on it.

```
total_sum = sum(list2)
for el in list1:
    total_sum += sum(divmod(2 * el, 10))
```

or

```
total_sum = sum(list2) + sum(sum(divmod(2 * el, 10)) for el in list1)
```

**Playing with indices**

Instead of splitting the list into 2 lists, we could iterate over the (reversed) list once and handle differently elements at odd positions and elements at even positions.

We'd get something like:

```
def validate_credit_card_number(card_number):
    temp_list = [int(c) for c in str(card_number)]

    total_sum = 0
    for i, e in enumerate(reversed(temp_list)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            total_sum += e
        else:
            total_sum += sum(divmod(2 * e, 10))

    return total_sum % 10 == 0
```

Or the more concise solution taking advantage of the fact that the `divmod` trick works for both cases:

```
def validate_credit_card_number(card_number):
    total_sum = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(reversed(str(card_number))):
        e = int(c) * (2 if i % 2 else 1)
        total_sum += sum(divmod(e, 10))
    return total_sum % 10 == 0
```

or

```
def validate_credit_card_number(card_number):
    return sum(sum(divmod(int(c) * (2 if i % 2 else 1), 10))
               for i, c in enumerate(reversed(str(card_number)))) % 10 == 0
```

Comment: @HackersInside actually, I have other ideas that could somehow improve the solution. I'll try to update the answer when I am on a computer

Comment: @HackerInside I've edited my answer.

Comment: `2 if i % 2 else 1` → `i % 2 + 1`

Answer (score 3):

I assume that `card_number` is an integer. As such, you should not convert it to a `str`, nor convert it to a `list`. You should be doing integer operations only, not list operations.

For your learning purposes, I won't rewrite the algorithm for you, but try to rewrite it such that it's represented as a loop over the credit card number, which successively gets divided by 10.

Comment: How am I supposed to iterate over a number, even if I break the number to digits, I will have to store it in a list for further processing.

Comment: Nope. Successively divide the number by 10 and work with the modulus.

Comment: Ok, I will try that out. However, I was wondering what would be the cons of converting it to a list/str?

Comment: It's slower and uses (slightly) more memory.